# Prevent Xcode from building if there are warnings

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, compiler-warnings, compiler-flags

I want my Xcode project to have no warnings. How can I configure Xcode such that it won't build as long as there are warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set `treat warnings as errors = YES` in the build settings

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot -- I use it myself. it does inhibit building for me. maybe you defined it at the wrong level?

Comment: i've defined it both at the target and project level

Comment: just tried it again (30s ago, Xcode 4.5.2) -- is the RESOLVED column YES?

Comment: yes, currently I have "Treat Warnings as Errors = Yes" and I have a `Validate Warning`

Comment: "Treat Warnings as Errors" will only cause warnings from the compiler to be treated as errors. It won't cause other warnings, such as the "Validate Project Settings" warnings emitted by Xcode itself, to be treated as errors. I don't think there's any way to have warnings from other sources treated as errors.

Comment: @bdash appart from the validate thingy, every warning is an error AFAICS: `#warning "lala"` in your code for example, also triggers

Comment: As I said, that setting only affects warnings emitted by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `-Werr` switch to the compiler flags (on the Build phases tab, if I recall correctly). This will make the compiler treat all warnings as errors and it will choke on each warning.